# How to sort an array of strings using substring with Bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I am writing my first unix bash script and I find it really difficult because I've never used linux before. It is homework from university. I tried a lot of stuff and I've been looking for hours but I simply can't find the right solution. Can someone give me some directions of what to use to sort strings from array which look like this:

```
room_100056.dat 4
room_8973.dat 2
room_7764.dat 1
room_2092.dat 20
```

to this:

```
room_7764.dat 1
room_8973.dat 2
room_10056.dat 4
room_2092.dat 20
```

When sorting the initial array, I am creating a new array which contains the sorted data. The problem is that in the sorted array, the data is printed like this:

```
room_100056.dat 
room_8973.dat
room_7764.dat 
room_2092.dat
1
2
4
20
```

Code:

```
file=$1/*.dat

count_visits=()

for room in $file
do
   visits=$(grep "<Visit>" $room | wc -l)
   filename=$(basename $room)
   count_visits+=($filename$'\t'$visits)
done

sorted_visits=($(echo ${count_visits[@]} | tr " " "\n" | sort -g))
printf '%s\n' "${sorted_visits[@]}"
exit
```

Comment: You'll have bugs if your filenames have spaces unsell modifying `count_visits+=( "$filename"$'\t'"$visits" )`, and similarly quoting `"$room"`. In general, you should probably run this code through http://shellcheck.net/ and follow its advice.

Comment: I will have a look, thank you very much!

Comment: (though actually, if you wanted everything to work right when filenames contain spaces, you'd put the number in the *first* column and the filename after it; that would also make it only `sort -n` needed, without the `-k2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell `sort` to use the second column numerically:

```
printf '%s\n' "${count_visits[@]}" | sort -k2n
```

Comment: No reason not to make that `printf '%s\n' "${count_visits[@]}" | sort -k2n` and let the looping happen internally to `printf`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I often forget about this functionality of printf. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This worked great! I will further investigate sort because I guess I've missed something.